# Android: How to dispose labHelper of Google Wallet after purchase

Tags: android, android-pay

I am integrating Google wallet and start **labHelper** at the begining of buying.Normally **labHelper** is start at the time of activity **onCreate** and **dispose** at the time of activity **onDestroy**.So even though if we not using wallet service the labHelper is starting at the time of activity onCreate.

So I am trying to start **labHelper** at the time of starting purchase and dispose in **labhelperPurchase** finish listener. I am getting an Exception after purchasing.But money transefering is also happening there.

After one time purchasing , when i try to purchase second time it shows "**TRANSACTION FAILED**"

**LabHelper Intialization**

```
 mHelper = new IabHelper(FrendyActivity.this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");
            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null)
                return;

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
            }
        }

    });
```

**After Purchasing this is the code for dispose**

```
   mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(FrendyActivity.this,
            SkuItem, code,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, type);


     IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new                    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
  if (mHelper != null)
        mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null

dealWithPurchaseSuccess(result, purchase);
}
```

After one time purchase, when I try to purchase the producat again am getting error the **labHelper is already start**

How to dispose labHelper properly after the purchase?

Comment: can you paste some code of purchase item..

Comment: updated with code @virendrao

Comment: are you sure this is purchase code because i remember we call something like launchPurchaseFlow..

Comment: updated the full flow @virendrao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: You should not dispose the iabHelper after a purchase is made. The API is not designed like that.

You should not even try to start and stop the API in methods other than onCreate and onDestroy. But if you really want it and you choose to do so create a new instance of the iabhelper first, don't reuse it.

But I suggest that you remove the dispose call in onIabPurchaseFinished and only call it in the onDestroy method.

Comment: in whatsapp  if we looking running service in setting we cant see "com.app.vendingbilling" service is running. that service run only at the time of purchase in whatsapp. But here  that vending billing service is runing at the time of application starting even though not purchasing. @Rolf ツ

Comment: That's probably because the purchase process in whatsapp only starts when the user navigates to the purchase activity.